# Use of undeclared identifier 'RKClient' after install RestKit

Tags: ios, xcode, restkit

After I installed RestKit according to instructions (get source with github) and after importing , I get a "Use of undeclared identifier 'RKClient'" Error in XCode.

- https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x
- https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-as-a-Git-Submodule

According the instructions, after installation and linking, I've put following code in didFinishedLaunchingWithOptions:

```
RKClient *client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURLString:@"http://restkit.org"];
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

RKClient is no part of RestKit 0.20.x anymore. RestKit now use AFNetworking under the hood. You can access the new HTTP Client like that:

```
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient
```

See https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0

You'll find most of the changes about the upgrade :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed the latest RestKit, i.e. 0.20pre2 version? If yes, than you're dealing with the same problems as I was 30 minutes ago. The thing is that API changed drastically from 0.10 to 0.20 versions, and the documentation is still describing things as of version 0.10. Regarding your particular problem, the RKClient class doesn't exist anymore in 0.20, and the whole approach to networking has changed.